# Powershell to build folder structures

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate building a folder structure daily on a server. The script works, but for some reason it's building it on my desktop instead of the server.

```
#get date info
$ymd = Get-Date -Format yyyy_MM_dd

#name server paths
$x = '\\server\x'

#build out the internal retouch structures for the projects
'folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3\a', 'folder3\b' |  % {New-Item -Name "$x\$ymd\$_" -ItemType 'Directory'}
```

Even if I type the server path out it builds it on my desktop:

```
#get date info
$ymd = Get-Date -Format yyyy_MM_dd

#name server paths
$x = '\\server\x'

#build out the internal retouch structures for the projects
'folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3\a', 'folder3\b' |  % {New-Item -Name "\\server\x\$ymd\$_" -ItemType 'Directory'}
```

The path that it's building it is not `\\server\x\$ymd\...` it's `C:\Users\username\Desktop\server\x\$ymd\...`

This happens if I run it in ISE or right click and run with powershell. How do I tell it to use the server path literally and not build it in the local environment? I have no issues accessing the server and use powershell on the server everyday, I haven't tried making the folder structure like this before so I assume I am overlooking something simple in the code.

Comment: This is because you're using `-Name` instead of `-Path` :)

Comment: Submit this as an answer and i'll mark it correct.

Comment: There, I added an answer. Glad it worked :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon if you submit your reply as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I already did, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you don't use `-Path` the current location is used as default. This is what [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.1) for this cmdlet says:

> "... The default is the current location when Path is omitted ..."

Also, it's good to know that `-Path` is the parameter at position 0 for this function. If you put the path without using any argument you wouldn't have had this problem :)

Comment: @Garrett No problem, glad it worked for you :)